# Upgrade to the latest php by aptitude

Tags: php, php5, apt, aptitude

I'm install php5 by aptitude, but php release the new version and recommend we upgrade.
But I unwant to compile the new version by myself.
How to upgrade the php to the newest version by aptitude?

Comment: Which PHP version do you currently have, and which version do you want to use?

Comment: I'm using (PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10 with Suhosin-Patch) and want to use 5.3.18 which is the newest at the time of writing.

Comment: I suggest you update your ubuntu to 12.04 and go with the 5.3.10 provided there. Bugfixes and security issues from upstream are backported to the Ubuntu package.

Answer (score 2):

You explain that you use the `php-5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10` package. I then assume that you use Ubuntu 9.10 which is an unsupported version of Ubuntu. I suggest you simply upgrade your box to the latest LTS (12.04) and use the provided package (version 5.3.10) of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can patch PHP 5.3.18 only with a modified Suhosin patch. The original one is not working. See here: http://www.itkb.ro/kb/linux/patch-suhosin-pentru-php-5318

Comment: For PHP 5.3.21 here is another updated patch http://www.itkb.ro/kb/linux/patch-suhosin-pentru-php-5321

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a ppa like [this](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/php5) that tries to keep up with current releases or wait till it hits the repository you are using. Or go to [php](http://www.php.net/downloads.php) and [install from the rpms](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/php5) they offer.